# Dark souls 2 what to do with unused weapons

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have played games like diablo 2 or never winter nights, and there you could trade your weapons for gold.

I have been playing Dark Souls 2 in xbox but I can't find anyone to trade my useless weapons and armors.

what can I do with my unused stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a trader called [Gavlan](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Gavlan) that you can sell all your unwanted gear to for souls. He appears in three locations, one after the other.

1. No-man's Wharf
2. Harvest Valley
3. Doors of Pharros.

He will not appear in any of the later locations until after he has been found and spoken to once in the previous location, but once he reaches the Doors of Pharros, he will stay there.

Comment: will he still be there if I have found him, but not spoken to him?(to go back and grab my junk and come back to sell him)

Comment: Yes, I do believe so.

Comment: @tinybyte, a word of warning though. Dark Souls isn't anything like Diablo or most traditional RPGs. Most weapons are viable when fully upgraded, even more than that, there's a lot, a LOT of good end game weapons and armor, and instead you pick based on movement sets, or particular resistances for shields. Don't sell everything you might find useless right now or you might regret it later on.